# Retrieve deeply nested value from mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called user which has linkedInstitutions as banks and banks have multiple accounts. The schema below depicts the structure. I want to just get all the bankaccountIds in array like below.

User Collection

```
{
        "userId" : "user1",
        "linkedInstitutions" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e91b32107d234196029c55c"),
                "institutionId" : "ins_3",
                "accounts" : [
                    {
                        "status" : "open",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5e91b32107d234196029c55d"),
                        "bankAccountId" : "nvQGQmZarySWBExXe13mTorxyzNe7Ef6BdaZQ",
                        "type" : "depository",
                        "balances" : {
                            "available" : 100,
                            "current" : 110,
                            "isoCurrencyCode" : "USD",
                            "limit" : null
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to have output in such format

```
{
   "bankAccountIds":[
      "nvQGQmZarySWBExXe13mTorxyzNe7Ef6BdaZQ",
      "bZzGzeBvMLHWMzaZXoxvT4vr8mAe9KtVw5RE6"
   ]
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$addFields` to elevate the nested field to automatically flatten it, and then `$project`. See full example here. https://runkit.com/embed/i4pe8krhpmrm

```js
let pipeline = [{
    "$addFields": {
      "bankAccountIds": "$linkedInstitutions.accounts.bankAccountId"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$bankAccountIds" },
  {
    "$project": {
      "bankAccountIds": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Result

```js
[ { bankAccountIds: ["nvQGQmZarySWBExXe13mTorxyzNe7Ef6BdaZQ"] } ]
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting bankAccountIds in a double dimensional array
db.account.aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
      "bankAccountIds": {
        "$concatArrays": "$linkedInstitutions.accounts.bankAccountId"
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: {
 "bankAccountIds" : [
  [
   "nvQGQmZarySWBExXe13mTorxyzNe7Ef6BdaZQ",
   "bZzGzeBvMLHWMzaZXoxvT4vr8mAe9KtVw5RE6",
   "mvXGXWQdKmSV57BZpLQ9t1QvbwnmKNcL5bG9e",
   "ywWXW9GL74iWZ5g746xkTx9DEBA3pdcyQ9Jon",
   "9JMaMWqQzPUREDWe48jQHm3EbBgVPLuRmL7kx",
   "vvWwWbEZNxSADqwyxlzBUNpZ1yrz4xuWDjLgQ",
   "RqyayJWvKzc8GDLp9VblCqBoy81EkNHRQK6wg",
   "6pb3bJRjqaUXy4GlWJjqSRNdaoJDzWtgRWEmR"
  ]
 ]
}

Comment: You can just $unwind the array before the $project. I have edited the example